# Integer Solutions to an Ellipse from Parameterization?

Tags: number-theory, conic-sections

I have an ellipse in the form of $$x^2 + xy + y^2 = 1009,$$ which I have parameterized into the following:

$$x = \frac{-35t^2 - 16t + 27}{t^2+t+1}$$ and

$$y = \frac{27t^2+70t+8}{t^2+t+1}.$$

I saw that for the ellipse $x^2 - xy + y^2 - k^2 = 0$, integer solutions could be found through parameterization on an older forum post, which is why I tried to do the same with this ellipse. Is it possible to do this through the parameterization of this ellipse? What are the next steps after I have parameterized the ellipse?

If not, what is the widely-accepted method of solving ellipses in the integers?

Comment: multiply by 4 and complete the square in the variables, you get $3 u^2 + v^2 = 4036,$ not too long by hand. Because of all the symmetry of the initial problem this becomes a large numer of related representations, all really the same. If $(u,v)$ works, so does $(-u,v)$ and various others.

Comment: $1009$ is a prime of the form $3k+1$, hence it is represented for sure by the quadratic form $x^2+xy+y^2$, since the class number of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is one. $$ 8^2+8\cdot 27+27^2 = 1009$$ can be found by Fermat's descent, one does not need a parametrization of all the rational points on the ellipse.